# Row Number column is not getting disappeared in LWC data table

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

Im using a data table. I can see Row index number is visible even if I have removed **show-row-number-column**

```
<lightning-datatable
                        key-field="Id"
                        data={data}
                        columns={columns}
                        selected-rows={selectedRows}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                        sorted-by={sortBy}
                        sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
                        onsort={handleSortdata}
                        onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                        hide-checkbox-column=true
                        onsave={handleSave}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`show-row-number-column` is forced on if you use inline editing, as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

> By making a column editable, the show-row-number-column attribute is always true and the number column is displayed.

Comment: You're a gift to the sfdx community; thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

@sfdxfox is right but you can still override this using some CSS. Add below code to the css file:

```
.hideFirstColTable table th:first-child, .hideFirstColTable table td:first-child{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Add class to the datatable:

```
           <div class="hideFirstColTable">
               <lightning-datatable
                        key-field="Id"
                        data={data}
                        class="hideFirstColTable"
                        columns={columns}
                        selected-rows={selectedRows}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                        sorted-by={sortBy}
                        sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
                        onsort={handleSortdata}
                        onrowselection={handleRowSelection}
                        hide-checkbox-column=true
                        onsave={handleSave}>
              </lightning-datatable>
          </div>
```

Comment: This only works in a synthetic Shadow DOM. In the real Shadow DOM, this wouldn't work, because outer CSS isn't supposed to bleed into child components.